# What are the pros & cons of taking a PMP practice exam as a "pre-assessment?"

Tags: pmp, certification

I'm pursuing my PMP certification, and while I have many years of PM experience, I have only just started my 35 contact hours of training for the PMP. At the beginning of that course, the instructor mentioned that if I join PMI that PMP practice exams are available as part of my membership.

It occurred to me that I could take a PMP practice exam as a "pre-assessment," which would help me to know what areas I need the most study. However, I'm not sure if there are disadvantages to this approach, e.g., that PMI only provides a single practice exam, one I would like to "save" for when I'm done studying so I can judge my ability to proceed to the real exam (if I had already taken it, I couldn't re-take and make use of the results, since I'd have seen the answers on my prior exam attempt).

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of places that offer free PMP practice questions (eg http://www.oliverlehmann.com/sample-questions-pmp-self-tests.html).

Practise exams are only really useful if you feel you're ready to sit the real exam - they'll show you whether you're ready or not. Get closer to the time when you can take the exam before using a paid practice exam. In the meantime, study and save your money.

PMI are notoriously good at selling the benefits of giving them money. Remember, that's what they're doing...selling something.

Answer (score 1):

PMI does not publish its questions nor do they provide practice exams.  There are a ton of PMP prep providers out there with questions of their own.  Taking them when I was preparing to sit for the exam, I discovered that the so called practice questions were substantially harder than the questions on the actual exam.  While this is completely opinion based, I think those providers purposely make those questions extremely difficult in order to increase anxiety so that they can sell additional prep services.  I have no idea if these questions truly prepare anyone to take the test.  Maybe they do, maybe they don't.  What they succeed in doing is making your bank account less and their revenues higher.  There can be no debate about that.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding PMI provides no pre-assessment tests. However there are various sites in public domain that provide free practice tests. You can give one to assess where you stand as of today. Please generalize your results as one test may not give any specific feedback where you are week or strong. It is always advisable as already advised by mwan, to take test after preparation.

Answer (score 0):

I studied for PMP in 2014 and I haven't heard about pre-assessment questions they give. The only thing about questions, that if you are PMI member, you can access their library. I found there a book with ~500 sample questions. They were pretty simple comparing to another sources.
I recommend you to look for some online courses (I took my 35 PDU hours from such course), they usually provide you test run of full 4-hour assessment. Or you can buy test-run assessment as a separate piece.

Several sources I used:

1. http://www.pmstudy.com/enroll.asp#PMP - they have one free simulated test
2. http://www.pmcampus.com/400qupmsiex.html
3. https://www.udemy.com there are a lot of materials, udemy has often provide discounts for majority of courses up to 90%
4. http://www.simplilearn.com/project-management/pmp-certification-training

Beware about questions that are outdated, there are tons of them over the Internet already. Look for the reference to recent PMBOK version.

Also, one of my favorites books -  [Rita Mulcahy PMP Exam Prep](http://store.rmcproject.com/pmp-exam-prep-eighth-edition-updated?_ga=1.61581868.1843463337.1454600581), there are a number of sample questions after each chapter.

Good Luck!